Some conditions of existence and uniqueness of ODE
I was studying the conditions of existence and uniqueness of ODE and I met some questions for different conditions as follows. We know that the classical theorem of existence and uniqueness of ODE is

Consider the ODE $\dot{x}=f(t,x), x(t_0)=x_0$, $t\in\mathbb{R},x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Assume $f(t,x)$ is continuous on the rectangle $D\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and satisfies Lipschitz condition w.r.t. $x$ for $(t,x)\in D$. Then for any $(t_0,x_0)\in D$, there exists a unique solution of the ODE passing through $(t_0,x_0)$.


When I read paper , I found some authors assume that $f(t,x)$ satisfies Lipschitz condition as follows, which is a little bit different from above.


For any compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, there exists a constant $L$ (independent of t) such that $||f(t,x)-f(t,y)||\leq L||x-y||$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R},x\in K$.

I know that in the classical theorem, the Lipschitz constant may depend on $t$, but what can we say more in this situation?

Also, some author assume that $f$ is admissable, that is,



$f(t,x)$ is continuous w.r.t. $(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
For any compact set $K\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f(t,x)$ is bounded and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times K$.


Can the definition of admissable guarantee that the solution of the ODE is uniqueness?

The Lipschitz conditions are the same. It might be easier to reply, if you describe why you think they are different. Is it because the other author wrote independent of t?
